# Need to write custom User model in DJango and return pre stored json file in response

Tags: python, django

Just started learning Python/Django 5 days back. Need to write an API where it gets 'username', 'password', 'password2' in request  and it should store username in some User object. And if the username already exists in User, then just return simple error message: "username is duplicate".

I am using User class from django.contrib.auth.models.  Which returns a BIG response[More than 1000 lines] , if username is not duplicate and stored successfully.

**Question 1**:  ***Solved  Now. Looking for answer for Question 2.***

I want to return simple one line message in response , if username is not duplicated and stored successfully.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password


class RegisterSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True, validators=[validate_password])
password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=True)

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'password', 'password2', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    

def validate(self, attrs):
    if attrs['password'] != attrs['password2']:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({"password": "Password fields didn't match."})
        

    return attrs

def create(self, validated_data):
    user = User.objects.create(
        username=validated_data['username']
    )
def validate_username(self, value):
    if User.objects.filter(username__iexact=value).exists():
        raise serializers.ValidationError("A user with this username already exists.")
    return value

    
    user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
    user.save()

    return user
```

**Question 2**:

I want to write an API, which on a GET call , returns pre-stored simple json file. This file should be pre-stored in file system.  How to do that?

register is app name. static is folder inside register. There I keep stations.json file.  register/static/stations.json.

**settings.py**:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'register/static/')
]
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .serializers import RegisterSerializer
from rest_framework import generics
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.conf import settings
import json



class RegisterView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegisterSerializer
    
    
def get_stations(request):
    with open(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + '/stations.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from register.views import RegisterView
from . import views



urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', RegisterView.as_view(), name='auth_register'),
    path('stations/', views.get_stations, name='get_stations'),
]
```

setup/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include('register.urls')),
]
```

When I hit GET request from Postman: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stations/",

I get error: 500 Internal server error.

TypeError
        at /api/stations/

Answer (score 2):

#### 1. For username validation, you can just override User class:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.contrib.auth.validators import UnicodeUsernameValidator
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class User(AbstractUser):
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = "AUTH_USER_MODEL"

    username_validator = UnicodeUsernameValidator()

    username = models.CharField(
        _("username"),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_(
            "Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only."
        ),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            "unique": _("username is duplicate"),
        },
    )
```

#### 2. To make a GET view that sends data from a JSON file, first you need to create it in your static directory.

views.py:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.conf import settings
import json

def get_data(request):
    with open(settings.STATICFILES_DIRS[0] + '/data.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    return JsonResponse(data)
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('data/', views.get_data, name='get_data'),
]
```

Comment: So I need to import this User in RegisterSerializer as: "from setup.register.models import User"  [setup is project name, register is app name]. Correct?

Comment: Also, do I need to use "from django.db import models"  at top of User Model?

Comment: It says, "NameError: name 'username_validator' is not defined"

Comment: You can define this model wherever you want. You don't need to use "from django.db import models".  You can remove username_validator from username field, or just import it and define. I have remade answer with import and definition.

Comment: I think the best way for you to understand what you need to change would be going to source code of AbstractUser and just go throw it's implementation. There you will probably find this BIG error and where to override it.

Comment: Not sure. But when I remove "from django.db import models" from top of User model, it says, "models.CharField(,   ---  NameError: name 'models' is not define"

Comment: Also , new issues now:    ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Group.user_set' for 'auth.User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'register.User.groups'.
        auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor 'Permission.user_set' for 'auth.User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'register.User.user_permissions'.

Comment: Yes, sorry I am stupid, I have fixed imports. And the Error is probably because you need to provide this custom user module in your settings.py:

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.User'

Where users is the name of module and User the name of model in models.py

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252085/discussion-between-android-and-banboniera).